# How to extract substrings in scala

Tags: scala

This is my code that I have used to try to solve the problem:

```
Source.fromFile(file).getLines()
  .foreach{ line => 
    line.split(" - - | \"POST | HTTP/1.1\" ")
      .foreach(word => println(word))
  }
```

This is three of my strings

```
192.168.9.230 - - [24/Apr/2017:08:58:06 +0800] "POST /dvr-gateway/api/genl/user/login HTTP/1.1" 200 211
192.168.32.145 - - [24/Apr/2017:08:58:07 +0800] "POST /dvr-gateway/api/genl/org/find HTTP/1.1" 200 126
192.168.2.54 - - [24/Apr/2017:08:58:52 +0800] "POST /dvr-gateway/api/genl/user/login HTTP/1.1" 200 211
```

I just want the IP address and address of the file.
Example, I want it print to:

```
192.168.9.230
/dvr-gateway/api/genl/user/login
```

Comment: I made some changes to your code to only show the essence of the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The easiest way to solve this would be to assign the results from `split` to a variable and only keep the first and third elements.

```
Source.fromFile(file).getLines().foreach{ line => 
  val splits = line.split(" - - | \"POST | HTTP/1.1\" ")
  List(splits(0), splits(2)).foreach(word => println(word))
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much ,it's work. Now I have a new question, my code changed spark streaming，use this line "textFile.flatMap（_。split（“”））". What should I do?

Comment: @cyfckl2008 If you have a new question I would suggest opening a new question here on the site. I'm not entirely sure what you want to accomplish.